# Django admin panel throws 404 when passing any url parameters

Tags: django, django-admin

Django admin panel throws 404 when passing any url parameters
Example url:

/admin/app/model/ - OK

/admin/app/model/?foo=bar - 404

/admin/app/model/?p=1 - 404

Nginx+uwsgi

Project urls file (admin,admin_tools,application urls)

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
import restaurant.views
import club.views
import hotel.views
import custom_app.views
import cart.views
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib import admin
import settings

handler404 = 'custom_app.views.handler404'
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),

    (r'^$', custom_app.views.Index.as_view()),
    (r'^restaurant$', restaurant.views.Index.as_view()),
    (r'^which$', csrf_exempt(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='custom_app/which.html'))),
    (r'^cart/add', cart.views.AddToCart.as_view()),
    (r'^cart/delete', cart.views.RemoveFromCart.as_view()),
    (r'^cart/send', cart.views.SendCart.as_view()),
    (r'^cart/delivery', cart.views.SetDelivery.as_view()),
    (r'^restaurant/about', restaurant.views.About.as_view()),
    (r'^restaurant/payment', restaurant.views.Payment.as_view()),
    (r'^restaurant/vip', restaurant.views.Vip.as_view()),
    (r'^restaurant/menu/(?P<slug>.+)', restaurant.views.Menu.as_view()),
    (r'^restaurant/menu/', restaurant.views.Menu.as_view()),
    (r'^restaurant/cart/', cart.views.Basket.as_view()),
    (r'^restaurant/tables/', restaurant.views.Tables.as_view()),
    (r'^restaurant/success_ordering', restaurant.views.SuccesTableOrder.as_view()),
    (r'^vacancy', custom_app.views.Vacancy.as_view()),
    (r'^hotel$', hotel.views.Main.as_view()),
    (r'^hotel/services', hotel.views.Services.as_view()),
    (r'^hotel/room/(?P<room>\d+)$', hotel.views.Main.as_view()),
    (r'^hotel/order/option/toggle$', hotel.views.ToggleOption.as_view()),
    (r'^hotel/order/date/toggle$', hotel.views.ToggleDate.as_view()),
    (r'^hotel/order/send$', hotel.views.Send.as_view()),
    (r'^club/events/old/(?P<year>\d+)/(?P<month>\d+)', club.views.OldEvents.as_view()),
    (r'^club/events/old/', club.views.OldEvents.as_view()),
    (r'^club/about', club.views.About.as_view()),
    (r'^club/event/(?P<pk>\d+)', club.views.DetailEvent.as_view()),
    (r'^club$', club.views.Main.as_view()),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),


)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
            }),
    )
```

Nginx configuration file:

```
server
{
        listen  %server_ip%;
        server_name custom.ru www.custom.ru;
        root /home/custom/www/;


       location ~* ^/resize/([\d\-]+)/([\d\-]+)/(.+)$ {
            alias /home/custom/www/custom/$3;
            image_filter resize $1 $2;
            image_filter_buffer 2M;
            error_page 415 = /empty;
        }

        location ~* ^/crop/([\d\-]+)/([\d\-]+)/(.+)$ {
            alias /home/custom/www/custom/$3;
            image_filter crop $1 $2;
            image_filter_buffer 2M;
            error_page 415 = /empty;
        }


        location = /empty {
            empty_gif;
        }


        location /
        {
                root /home/custom/www/custom/;
                uwsgi_pass unix:///home/custom/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_PASS   unix:///home/custom/tmp/uwsgi.sock;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_CHDIR  /home/custom/www/custom/;
                uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCRIPT wsgi;
        }

        location /static
        {
                alias /home/custom/www/custom/static/;
        }

        location /media
        {
                alias /home/custom/www/custom/media/;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { alias /home/custom/www/favicon.ico; }

}
```

Comment: have you write any url for that Query string?

Comment: What's `action`? Is that something you defined in `urls.py`? Any chance we can see your `urls.py`?

Comment: acton = model (sry, its my fault)
/admin/application/model/

Comment: Do you get Django's 404 page or nginx's? In case of the latter show your nginx URL patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Try

/admin/app/action?foo=bar

instead of /?

The extra / is looking for a resource at that location

Comment: /admin/app/model?p=1 redirect to /admin/app/model/?p=1 . And more - pagination redirect oO /admin/app/model/?page=1 redirect to /admin/app/model/?e=1 ;(